# In a Swift app, I want to create a class that holds data that can be updated and displayed across multiple SwiftUI views

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-class

Here's the class:

```
class DataManager {
    static let shared = DataManager()

    var data: String = "Initial"
        
    private init() {}

    func updateData(newData: String) {
        self.data = newData
    }
}

let sharedManager = DataManager.shared
```

I update the data property in one view based with an onTapGesture in that view:

```
sharedManager.updateData(newData: "New")
```

When I check the value of sharedManager.data in that view, it is updated.

But when I look at sharedManager.data in a different view, it is not updated. How can I update that code to get it to work as expected: Update a property of an instance of a class in one view, have the update show in another?

Comment: Have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app: 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app). This will show you how to `Update a property of an instance of a class in one view, have the update show in another?`

Comment: Got it, I added @Observable and it now it works the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI may not be updating the other views because your class is not set up for observation.

Try adding the @Observable macro:

```
@Observable
class DataManager {
...
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, that is the additional I needed. @Observable makes the data changes consistent across the app.